# How can I make a timeout using floats?

Tags: c, time

I want to make a while loop that will say "Hello World" for 2 seconds and 500 milliseconds (2.5s). The code I made currently works with normal integers, but if I change it to use floats it stops working

Any idea?

Broken code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    float timeout = time(NULL) + 2.5;

    while(time(NULL) < timeout) {
        printf("Hello World\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep

Comment: Which platform are you on?  Using `clock_gettime()` or perhaps `gettimeofday()` would work on POSIX systems.

Comment: @OldProgrammer — the code isn’t going to sleep. It is hyperactive for 2.5 seconds.

Comment: The value returned by `time` was `1558189042`. By assigning that to `float` which does  not have enough significance, you can't add `2.5` meaningfully.

Comment: The `time()` function returns the time in seconds. You cannot just treat it as a float, or expect float addition to work. To pause program execution, you can use `sleep()` on POSIX or `Sleep()` on Windows. To use time values explicitly yourself, get a more accurate time reading with `clock_gettime()` on POSIX or `GetLocalTime` on Windows.

Comment: The code has more chance of working if you use `double`. Please never use `float` without having a very good reason.

Comment: Double worked, ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that:

1. You're using a `float` to represent the result of `time()`, which is a big integer, and could cause the conversion to be inaccurate due to the nature of floating point values.
2. The precision of the `time()` function is only good down to the second, so your code will never run for 2.5 seconds, but will always run for 3 seconds, since you can only proceed in steps of 1 second.

To solve the issue, without using a floating value (which does not make sense since most of the functions that work with time use integral values), you can use the [`gettimeofday()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) function on Linux, or the [`GetSystemTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtime) function if you are on Windows.

**Linux:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

unsigned long long get_time(void) {
    struct timeval time;
    gettimeofday(&time, NULL);

    return time.tv_sec * 1000 * 1000 + time.tv_usec;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    unsigned long long timeout = get_time() + 2500000;
    // Accurate to the microsecond.
    // 2.5 s == 2 500 000 us

    while(get_time() < timeout) {
        printf("Hello World\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Windows:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

unsigned long long get_time(void) {
    SYSTEMTIME time;
    GetSystemTime(&time);

    return time.wSecond * 1000 + time.wMilliseconds;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    unsigned long long timeout = get_time() + 2500;
    // Accurate to the millisecond.
    // 2.5 s == 2 500 ms

    while(get_time() < timeout) {
        printf("Hello World\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE** that on Windows the accuracy is down to the millisecond, while on Linux it is down to the microsecond.

Comment: The precise numeric type aliased by `time_t` is not specified; it can be any [real type](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.1), integer or floating point. There was certainly at least one historical implementation which used floating point.

Comment: Not really trying to describe the specific decisions that had to be made when writing the libc/POSIX standard for time values here. All I know is that I've never seen or heard of implementations using floating point values, so it makes sense to assume integral values for such a simple and high level problem.

Answer (score -3):

I'd stick with integers.

You could do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
  long int timeout = time(NULL)*10 + 25;

  while(time(NULL)*10 < timeout) 
  {
    printf("hello, world\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't measure 2.5 seconds using a clock with 1 second resolution.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: You can, just that it's not accurate.;)